# how to NOT have repeating rows in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct

My schemea is a customer table that joins to the table with the address. Some of the address have two: a billing and a shipping.

How can I get one customer per line with either a billing or shipping.

I feel like should use a DISTINCT but if I do, it will delete my customers that have a billing and shipping address attached.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGXsJ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpzNr.png)

```
SELECT
    Firstname,
    LastName,
    Line1,
    City,
    State,
    ZipCode,
FROM
    Customers as c
    INNER JOIN Addresses as a ON c.CustomerID = a.CustomerID
ORDER BY
    c.CustomerID
```

Comment: Post your table schemas here for clarity.

Comment: Just Posted pics

Comment: Please mention then name and version of dbms you are using.

Comment: Please don't use images for data, use formatted text. And what are your desired results - especially in the case when a customer has both a billing address and a shipping address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `row_number()over()` and common table expression you can select first row from table `Addresses` for each customer. Then join that table with customer table to have single row per customer.

```
with addess as 
(
  select *,row_number()over(partition by customerid order by addressid)rn from Addresses 
)
SELECT
    Firstname,
    LastName,
    Line1,
    City,
    State,
    ZipCode,
FROM
    Customers as c
    INNER JOIN Address as a ON c.CustomerID = a.CustomerID and rn=1
ORDER BY
    c.CustomerID
```

A slower solution with subquery:

```
SELECT
    Firstname,
    LastName,
    Line1,
    City,
    State,
    ZipCode,
FROM
    Customers as c
    INNER JOIN Address as a ON c.CustomerID = a.CustomerID and 
    a.AddressID=(select min(addressid) from Addresses where CustomerID=c.CustomerID)
ORDER BY
    c.CustomerID
```

Comment: We can’t use that. Our classes are in the beginning stages so we can only use a join of some sort.

Comment: which dbms you are using?

Comment: MyGuitarShop is the DB

Comment: I have revised your my answer. Please check.

Comment: MyGuitarShop is your database name But DBMS name would be SQL Server, MYSQL, Oracle etc.

Comment: oh sorry. SQL Server!

Comment: I have added a new answer. Please check and confirm.